# Customise charging for MacBook Pro?

Tags: macos, high-sierra, battery, charging

Is there any way to customise the charging schedule for my MacBook Pro (2017)? Essentially, I have long periods when my machine is plugged into the mains due to running intensive models, unattended, and I don't want to risk the battery dying mid-simulation.

What I would like to achieve is some app (or otherwise) to tell the machine to stop charging when at 100% (despite still being plugged in) and to resume charging when reaching some other battery percentage (say 25%) - does an app like this exist?

Unfortunately, Googling and searching this site about batteries produces swathes of hardware issues, rather than this question - so sorry if it is a duplicate.

Comment: Also related: [Prevent Macbook from Charging past a certain level](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/322977/168832) and [Should I disconnect my MacBook Pro's power cord when the battery is fully charged?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/12271/168832).

Comment: Sorry, but why do you want to stop charging at 100%? Once the MB reaches 100% charge it will run off the power adapter.