# Can I tell my Mac to charge to 80% only?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, battery, charging, power

I leave my MacBook plugged in for days at a time, so the battery stays charged to 100%. <s>Despite Apple claims to the contrary</s>*, I believe that the battery's capacity would be better preserved if I could keep it at an 80% state-of-charge, so that is my goal unless someone can convince me that taking it above 80% charge has benefits to counterbalance any drawbacks.

https://www.apple.com/batteries/maximizing-performance/

Here are various options, (1) being my most preferred:

1. A setting to automatically maintain battery at 80% SoC (like my Tesla has)
2. A setting/command to use the AC adapter for running power only ("not charging" state)
3. A command to tell my Mac to totally ignore the AC adapter power

(2) could be cobbled into (1) with some kind of script. Even if not possible from the Mac itself, (3) could be cobbled together with an IOT switch. But with (3), it's unclear the lower maintained SoC would outweigh the cost of the additional cycling.

* As of 11 Feb 2022, I can no longer find Apple claims that it's best to fully charge the battery.

Is there any app, command or setting that would let me disable charging from the power adapter?

Comment: Many products mentioned, here is another one: https://github.com/alaneuler/batteryKid

Comment: If that’s an answer, can you add it proper, please @Alaneuler

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Use [bclm](https://github.com/zackelia/bclm) (Apple Silicon with macOS 13.0 or higher and Intel Macs)

Follow the instructions on GitHub:

1. Download signed and notarized binary from releases.
   (Alternatively, you can also get it from Homebrew or compile it manually. Read the GitHub readme for more details.)
2. Extract battery tool

```
$ unzip bclm.zip
$ sudo cp bclm /usr/local/bin
```

3. Set battery limit

```
$ sudo bclm write 80
```

4. Verify battery limit to 80%

```
$ bclm read
```

5. Reset the limit back to 100% when needed

```
$ sudo bclm write 100
```

Notes:

- It might be better if you set it even lower, for example, 60% or 70%. Then, before you need to use it on battery for a long time, `bclm write 100`. You can automate this switching between 80% and full using `launchd` (read `man launchd.plist`).
- macOS show charge approximately 3-5% greater than the real value, so it may feel like the tool is not working initially. Use [coconutbattery](https://www.coconut-flavour.com/coconutbattery/) (GUI) or `ioreg -l | awk '$3~/Capacity/{c[$3]=$5}END{OFMT="%.3f";max=c["\"MaxCapacity\""];print(max>0?100*c["\"CurrentCapacity\""]/max:"?")}'`<sup>[1]</sup> to calculate real battery charge level.
- If you are using macOS Catalina or higher, you need to turn off the "Optimised battery charging" function for the tool to work properly, otherwise, the value you set might be overwritten.
- There is also a GUI version: [charge-limiter](https://github.com/godly-devotion/charge-limiter). Both work by setting the `BCLM` key in SMC to a custom value.

For Apple Silicon Macs and macOS 11 (Big Sur) and higher, use [AlDente](https://github.com/davidwernhart/AlDente).

Alternatively, there is a more lightweight tool with a command line version: [battery](https://github.com/actuallymentor/battery).

<sup>[1] <sub>No longer works with Apple Silicon Macs.</sub></sup>

Comment: My M1 Pro 16 inch Ventura 13.6 no longer self calibrates it's battery optimization ever since I installed Workspace One Intelligent Hub from VMWare for my corporation. I am using AlDente to force the 80% battery optimization. Thank you!

Comment: The "real battery charge level" command no longer works on Apple Silicone macs. Anyone know how to update it?

Comment: Have you tried the latest version of `bclm`?

Comment: @Seamus Could you please explain what you mean by your question? I think it might be valuable to still keep the link to `battery` tool since it works well with Apple Silicon macs which actually only have a binary charging on/off switch

Comment: I was just curious about your recent experience - if you have an Apple Si Mac. My system doesn't work as expected. I filed [an issue](https://github.com/zackelia/bclm/issues/33), but it was dismissed.  But yes - by all means - keep any links you have to `battery`; they seem to be more interested in functionality than `bclm`.

Comment: @Seamus I actually haven't tried `bclm` on my m1 max 16'' macbook since when I got it `bclm` seems to not support Apple Silicon yet (it seems like support is added recently)and `battery` seems to be written for Apple Silicon specifically, and I just stick with `battery` since because it works. I can try `bclm` but it seems like it requires a newer firmware version (not sure what that refers to specifically). If you can monitor the value of `CHWA` key using `smc` and see if that changes, that might give a clue as to why it's not charging. If it doesn't change then it's not an issue with `bclm`.

Comment: No - `bclm` definitely "supports" Apple Si Macs... they state this on their GitHub repo. Wrt firmware version, this statement from the `bclm` README.md file: *"For Apple silicon machines, only the values 80 and 100 are supported and firmware >= 13.0 is required."* But - I think you've made the better choice in using `battery`. WRT firmware: Yeah - I'm also unsure. I know firmware updates are included with OS upgrades, but have no idea where to get the version #.

Comment: Correction: `blcm read` to `bclm read`

Answer (score 21):

macOS 10.15.5 on a Mac notebook with Thunderbolt 3 ports has this option (even a bit smarter) embedded, see *Optimised battery charging*.

https://support.apple.com/kb/HT211094

[image: System Preferences: Battery]

Comment: Unfortunately, "even a bit smarter" is failing for me. The OS has yet to figure out when to stop at 80%, and I doubt it ever will (my routines are unpredictable)

Comment: Indeed. Not very smart at all :) I would much prefer to have a manual setting, instead of having to rely on hacks like given earlier.

Comment: If your 'routines are unpredictable', then that suggests you are actually unplugging it every now and again and using the battery, which means you don't need to keep it at 80% so much. By far a bigger factor in ageing is heat.

Comment: My routines are also unpredictable, but along the lines of draining it around 30% per week. I hardly use the battery, but this unpredictability has prevented Optmizing Battery Charging from reliably kicking in. Also, MacBooks are generally very good at keeping battery temperatures low despite the temperature of other parts of the laptop.

Comment: Case in point: [here](https://imgur.com/a/eeo7NMQ) is my battery usage for the last two weeks. I hardly use battery power but that's enough to prevent Optimized Battery Charging from kicking in (which has always been enabled).

Comment: Yeah, the OS seems really bad at handling if you unplug only occasionally, even after many months to learn — third-party software seems to be the way to go.  Having had batteries die in more than one previous MacBook, I'm happy to sacrifice 20% for longevity!

Comment: Same problem here on M3 MBP, the "Optimized" charger sometimes decides to charge it up to 100% and sometimes if it's at 100% it actually lets it run on battery down to 80% even though the charger is connected. It's like it can't make up its mind. I've only had it for 3 weeks though so maybe it's "learning" still..

Answer (score 12):

You can try [AlDente](https://github.com/davidwernhart/AlDente) (there is also a [Pro Version](https://apphousekitchen.com/)):

> - Charge Limiter allows you to set your maximum charging percentage between 20 and 100 percent. You can either set it by using the slide bar or by typing in the desired percentage in the field above and pressing enter afterwards.
> - Discharge - This feature allows your MacBook to run completely on Battery even if it is plugged in. Therefore, you can actively discharge your MacBook to a more healthy percentage. Unfortunately, while Discharge is activated, clamshell mode is not supported due to technical limitations.

Comment: AlDente has downsides, though. It's an app that runs, consumes noticeable amounts of CPU time, occupies space in the menu bar and overall does many more things. I wish there was a simpler solution for only limiting the charge to 80% on Apple Silicon macs.

Comment: @JanRychter I added a simpler solution to my answer.

Answer (score 7):

There are some new options for Macs with Apple Silicon. Apple refers to their system for battery charging as *"Optimized Battery Charging"*; the OP's question seems to be asking about *"Limited Battery Charging"*. I feel that many of the issues reported with Apple's *"Optimized Battery Charging"* have to do with ***how*** Apple has optimized it.

Apple's software is mostly all proprietary and closed-source, so there's no way to know for sure what's going on, but we do know that Apple relies on periodic *"battery calibration"* for reporting the state of charge. We also know that battery calibration requires occasional charging the battery to 100%.

Therein lies the problem:

> *Achieving the battery longevity benefits of maintaining an 80% charge level
>
> **VS.**
>
> When & how often to re-calibrate the battery by charging to 100% to maintain accurate reporting?*

How well Apple has balanced these competing objectives may depend quite a lot on the individual user's *usage profile*. Which may explain the [number of questions/complaints](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=apple+mac+optimized+battery+charging+issues&t=newext&atb=v369-1&ia=web).

Also: Given that Apple's "calibration" keeps the battery between 80% charge and 100% charge, one might wonder how effective a calibration can be if it's kept in such a narrow range. There's a good [article at the Battery University](https://batteryuniversity.com/article/bu-605-calibrating-smart-batteries-with-impedance-tracking) explaining how calibration works, and why it's valuable. But this is not how Apple does it... suffice it to say that apparently Apple has not read (or doesn't believe) this article.

If your experience with Apple's *"Optimized Battery Charging"* leaves you feeling less than enthusiastic, perhaps you should investigate one of the apps that implements *"Limited Battery Charging"*. Here's a short list of apps that implement *"Limited Battery Charging"* for Macs with Apple Silicon:

1. [AlDente - Charge Limiter, commercial edition](https://apphousekitchen.com/)
2. [AlDente - Charge Limiter, open-source edition](https://github.com/AppHouseKitchen/AlDente-Charge-Limiter)
3. [Battery-Toolkit; fm 'mhaeuser'](https://github.com/mhaeuser/Battery-Toolkit)
4. [battery; fm 'actuallymentor'](https://github.com/actuallymentor/battery)
5. [batt; fm 'charlie0129'](https://github.com/charlie0129/batt)
6. [bclm; fm 'zackelia'](https://github.com/zackelia/bclm) - see [this issue](https://github.com/zackelia/bclm/issues/33) before installing

In general, these *"Limited Battery Charging"* apps focus almost entirely on battery longevity, and leave the periodic calibration function to the user. This *may* amount to simply disabling the charge limiting function, and allowing the charger to charge to 100%.

Answer (score 6):

There is also [Energiza Pro](https://appgineers.de/energiza). It supports Apple silicon MacBooks and allows you to set flexible charging limits.
(Disclaimer: I'm the developer.)

[image]

Comment: What are the cons of your app?

Answer (score 2):

Tried below and it worked.

Open Terminal and run

```
xcode-select --install
git clone --recursive https://github.com/DevNulPavel/osx_battery_charge_limit
cd osx_battery_charge_limit
sudo python3 main.py -s 80
```

I set limit to 70 and it does stop charging until 72%

Comment: I am getting an error in the last step: osx_battery_charge_limit % sudo python3 main.py -s 80
ERROR: SMC out parse failed
valid "  BCLM  [ui8 ]  60 (bytes 3c)"
current "  BCLM  [    ]  no data"

Comment: [Intel only Macbook (OSX) limit maximum battery charge](https://github.com/DevNulPavel/osx_battery_charge_limit)

Answer (score 2):

If you don’t like the many open source options in this Q&A - one more lightweight app that works well is [Charge Limiter](https://github.com/godly-devotion/charge-limiter). It doesn’t work on Apple Silicon, so it’s for Intel based macOS systems.