# MacBook Optimized Battery Charging doesn't work

Tags: macbook-pro, charging

I bought a M1 MacBook Pro 5 months ago and have been using it plugged in almost ever since, the battery is extremely rarely worked (probably once every few weeks). *"Optimised battery charging"* is turned on and working correctly for months, it would stop charging and be on this status *"Charging On Hold (Rarely Used On Battery)"*.

About 2 months ago, I had to take it somewhere for a day so I clicked the *"Charge to Full Now"* button, and optimised charging has stopped working ever since. The battery is always 100% charged, *"Optimised battery charging"* is still checked in System Preferences, macOS 11.3. How do I get it to work again?

Note: *"Charge to Full Now"* may not be the cause, it's the most relevant thing I can think of that may have triggered the issue.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, except I **never** clicked the "Charge to Full Now" button (or ever changed any setting). My 2023 MacBook Pro Ventura 13.6.2 stopped using the 80% charge about 2 weeks ago; it stays plugged into charger 100% of the time (except when I move suddenly & the magsafe pulls out). This was a great feature... it's too bad Apple booted it.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the "smart" algorithm fails to predict correctly.  For example, if you don't use it on a regular basis, then the algorithm doesn't know when you'll need the 100% next, so it keeps it at 100% until it figures out your pattern of behaviour.

You can try unplugging in on a regular basis for a while, to allow it to start predicting your behaviour.  However, I would recommend simply to read [Can I tell my Mac to charge to 80% only?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/406957/can-i-tell-my-mac-to-charge-to-80-only) for other ways to get the battery to stop charging at 80%.