# Is it programmable to make macOS ignore the power adapter and use only the battery?

Tags: macos, mac, battery, power-management, ventura

There is a similar question [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/406957/can-i-tell-my-mac-to-charge-to-80-only), but what I want is make macOS ignore the power adapter totally not just stop charging (which means the operations on mac will drain the battery).

Aldente has a functionality called **discharge**, but it stops working on latest macOS Ventura. After some digging I found that the keys of SMC driver on Ventura are completely (almost) different from that on Monterey. Not sure if it is this making the functionality unavailable.

Answer (score 4):

No, as of macOS 13 there is no Apple supported means to ignore the power adapter and stop charging.

Please [tell Apple](https://www.apple.com/feedback); only Apple can reliably offer this behaviour.

### Private or Unintended

Unfortunately, Apple does not actively enable or support the behaviour you want. Any application or tool that provides this functionality is either using Apple's private System Programming Interface (SPI) or unintended behaviour within macOS's IOKit.

This explains why changes in macOS can affect third party tools that rely on undocumented or unintended functionality.

### IOPMLib: Public Interface

The public Application Programming Interface (API) for power management is [IOPMLib](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/iokit/iopmlib_h), which is part of [IOKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/iokit):

> ## IOKit
>
> Access hardware devices and drivers from your apps and services.

…

> ### IOPMLib.h
>
> IOPMLib provides access to common power management facilities, like initiating system sleep, getting current idle timer values, registering for sleep/wake notifications, and preventing system sleep.

Comment: So maybe Aldente is using some private API?